# How to scale bitmap with high quality and without crash in android

Tags: android, bitmap, scaling

I am downloading image using url, but after scaling it's crashing and scaling is not proper.
This is the code I have used,

```
//Code to fetch bitmap  
Bitmap bmp=HttpFetch.fetchBitmap(imageUrl);

//Scale bitmap

Bitmap myBitmap = getResizedBitmap(bmp, viewWidth, viewHeight);  

public static Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newWidth, int newHeight) {

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        int srcWidth = bm.getWidth();
        int srcHeight = bm.getHeight();

        int desiredWidth = newWidth;
        int desiredHeight = newHeight;

        int inSampleSize = 1;
        while(srcWidth / 2 > desiredWidth){
            srcWidth /= 2;
            srcHeight /= 2;
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }

        float desiredWidthScale = (float) desiredWidth / srcWidth;
        float desiredHeightScale = (float) desiredHeight / srcHeight;

        // Decode with inSampleSize
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inDither = false;
        options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;
        options.inScaled = false;
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(desiredWidthScale, desiredHeightScale);
        original = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        return original;
}
```

Could not find code to get BitmapFactory.Option using bitmap and most of the places it is using filename, is it possible to get BitmapFactory.Options using bitmap?

Kindly suggest better solution to scale bitmap when we download from network.

Comment: what lind of error you are getting in Logcat...?

Comment: I did not observe any error in logcat, it is not happening properly for some images and also crashing some times, not always. For me main prolem is how to get BitmapFactory.Options for bitmap downloaded from network.

Comment: In place of using `Bitmap.createBitmap` you can try using Bitmap.createScaledBitmap.

Answer (score 1):

```
original = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

This line returns an immutable Bitmap, after calling `getResizedBitmap()`, if you are trying to modify this Bitmap, it might result in a crash.

[Android#createBitmap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Matrix,%20boolean%29)

Please look up LogCat for details.